# Past perfect when the action is separated from the present by facts that are common knowledge to the speakers but not mentioned

Tags: grammaticality, past-perfect, french

Page 59 of *Learner English: A Teacher's Guide to Interference* reads:

> There is a tense in French which is formed like the English past
> perfect, and its usage corresponds generally to the English tense. But
> it can also be used when the action spoken about is separated from the
> present by facts that are common knowledge to the speakers - even
> though they may not be mentioned:
>
> ‘Yes, I am in Room 232.’ **‘But I **had asked** for a double room!’*

Is the sentence really ungrammatical though?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why is the Learner English text talking about French?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Interference between English and the students' languages is the subject of this book: *This updated edition is a practical reference guide which compares the relevant features of a student's own language with English, helping teachers to predict and understand the problems their students have.*

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the example presented as ungrammatical in that book is not truly ungrammatical in English.

People certainly **can** use the past perfect in English for these situations, just as they do in French.

And while it might be more common to use a simple (meaning non-compound) past in this scenario, there's nothing "wrong" with the past perfect version in English here.